# How can I get byte[] from bytea column with MyBatis?

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis, mybatis

I tried the following way.

Here is the query mapping:

```
<select id="getTypicalTaskMeasurementParameterValue" 
            parameterType="Integer" 
            resultType="byte[]">
    SELECT value 
    FROM typical_task_measurements_parameter_values 
    WHERE id_typical_task_measurement = #{typicalTaskMeasurementId}
</select>
```

Here is the method:

```
public byte[] getTypicalTaskMeasurementParameterValue(
    Integer typicalTaskMeasurementId);
```

And here is the error I got, trying to run the unit test against it:

```
nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: 
Error instantiating class [Ljava.lang.Byte; with invalid types () or values (). 
Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: [Ljava.lang.Byte;.<init>()
at ...
```

Moreover, setter method for this bytea staff is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says the problem pretty well.  There is no default constructor on `java.lang.Byte`.

You need a result map that will choose which constructor to use,  or implement your own TypeHandler.

Comment: Thank a lot. It's bad, that such a common situation tends me to write the custom Handler, but in my particular case, maybe it's even good, because there is JSON data in this column. So, I'd check this solution and approve your answer.

Answer (score -1):

first get `Object` instead of `byte[]`

```
public Object getTypicalTaskMeasurementParameterValue(
    Integer typicalTaskMeasurementId
);
```

Then change `Object` to `byte[]`.