# Which Mybatis TypeHandler to use with object stored as bytea in PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I use Mybatis mapper to perform SQL query (Postgres) which returns some fields of bytea type. There are different object types stored within this fields and I encountered an error with deserialization.

I have a mapper:

```
<mapper namespace="WorkflowMapper">
    <resultMap id="WorkflowResultMap" type="Workflow">
        <id column="id" property="id" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
        <result property="amount" column="amount" javaType="java.lang.Float" jdbcType="BLOB"/>
</resultMap>
<select id="findAllCustom" resultMap="WorkflowResultMap">
    SELECT
        procinst.proc_inst_id_ AS id,                                                  
        amount_VAR.bytes_      AS amount,
        ...
    FROM procinst
        ...
       -- Some JOINS to request vauels
</select>
</mapper>
```

In runtime I've got an error:

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column 'amount' from result set.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type float : \xaced00057372000f6a6176612e6c616e672e466c6f6174daedc9a2db3cf0ec02000146000576616c7565787200106a6176612e6c616e672e4e756d62657286ac951d0b94e08b0200007870412547ae
```

I tried to add `typeHandeler="org.apache.ibatis.type.FloatTypeHandler"`, but it has no influence on error.

I checked out the query at Datagrip and got next result:
[image: Screenshot]

**So, the question is: how to deserialize value stored in *bytea* type as object?**

**Edit:**
I'm sure that object stored as *bytea* type, because the value is stored in another table (I use Activi Engine Services to store the values and it's use same Mybatis library).

The table where object is being stored has next structure (take a look at **bytes_** field):

```
create table act_ge_bytearray
(
    id_ varchar(64) not null
        constraint act_ge_bytearray_pkey
            primary key,
    rev_ integer,
    name_ varchar(255),
    deployment_id_ varchar(64)
        constraint act_fk_bytearr_depl
            references act_re_deployment,
    bytes_ bytea,
    generated_ boolean
)
;
```

The object class has next structure:

```
public class Workflow implements Sortable
{
    private String id;
    private Float amount;

    // getters and setters are ommited
}
```

Comment: What object? I'm pretty sure you're not storing a `Float` as a `bytea`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get byte\[\] from bytea column with MyBatis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536043/how-can-i-get-byte-from-bytea-column-with-mybatis)